# Need Help looping through a hierarchy of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, loops, foreach

I have baseElements and elements, and every element has a parent element. So the user is given a base element and can then create new elements under that base element and then create more elements under each element they created. the Element class inherits from the BaseElement class so all baseElements and elements have an id and elements have an additional variable parentId. I used a single table to store both baseElements and elements.

So the hierarchy goes like this:

baseElement -> elements -> elements -> elements -> as many layers deep as the user wants to go. you can also have as many elements as you want on each level so it can branch out very quickly.

A user can create posts or comment on the base element and every element on every level of their hierarchy. So I have a table of posts which have an element id linking a post to which ever element or base element it belongs to.

I have my Dao, controller and everything setup to fetch everything from the database, but now I'm trying to find a way to display the total number of posts for a baseElement including all elements underneath that baseElement.

because each baseElement and element could have multiple elements and levels of elements under it I know I will need some kind of loop, but I can't conceptualize how the loop will work.

I know it will go something like this.

Get the number of posts with the baseElement id, then get all of the elements with that baseElement id in the parentID column and get all of the posts for each of these elements, then get all of the elements with each of those element ids in the parent column and get the number of posts from all of those, and basically keep going until I reach the bottom of the hierarchy of elements.

But I'm having trouble building this nested loop. I have a dao for baseElement/element and a dao for posts. It feels like the loop will be nested with how ever many layers as there are layers of elements which will be different for each user.

I want to be able to feed in an elementID and have it give me the total number of posts from that element down.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: hi @cliff2310 yea, sorry for the long winded question. I had a hard enough time explaining the issue, let alone trying to understand the issue when trying to solve it myself.  I will work on drafting this question in a better way and repost when I can. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a diagram of the relationships would help?